# how to do regex express with dollar sign $ as pattern in swift

Tags: swift

I am working on regex expression in swift and I get the error `quantifier '*' must appear after expression`. what does it mean and how could I resolve it? I test 2 different way

1. using range with extension String. the result is false when my pattern is `payment*$`

```
extension String {

    func matches(_ regex: String) -> Bool {
        range(of: regex, options: .regularExpression, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil
    }
}
let string = "payment a b c d add pdf pdf $5.12"
string.matches(#"payment"#) /// return true as expected
string.matches(#"payment*"#) /// return true as expected
string.matches(#"payment*$"#) /// return false, I expect to be true
```

2. I use the website [swiftregex.com](https://swiftregex.com/?s=H4sIAAAAAAAAA6VRwU6DQBD9lcnGxKoIy661SW9YOGxUaMr25HpAoBwElsCSSGq%2Fxj%2Fxy1xoghYPHnzJZmYyeW%2Fm7exRhZZottp4LuPvrnfH%2BIUQzdVMiGRvG%2BRgnSQ3h6F7iQwk0fIJZTop0LOBlK1l7pnvwgDX4R6MYH7IGd9yFvgwgfMYbH0uyut%2FQpRHC70mpha2LYIJ6at11NUyz2FXywLSospll9bH4WcEY5PQKZeO3LBtqjRW4EzX7rkGxrh%2FJsaiHH4OfivwNDlvYJ0q2Mj4FcKojFUb1d1fCvNRwZVtpiXcNpOt0lXWfO9AqUkWJ9Tbn8ODt52sE1jJooi0l6rKO3hQialbnx%2FzhUm1dX3AF306HRTp4%2BELou3S0xICAAA%3D). it generates the error

[image]

Comment: Escape it with `\$`, because dollar sign is a Regex token, so you need to escape it.

Comment: But your current issue is also the `*` part which is wrong as it should currently accepts `paymenttttttt` (only "t")... So `string.matches(#"payment*.*?\$"#)` seems to be working

Comment: i need to write a generate regex express to check `payment` or `payment*$` or `payment*$*`

Answer (score 0):

The `*` and `$` have very special meanings in regular expressions:

- The asterisk, `*`, is not a wildcard character. It means “zero or more occurrences” of the preceding element. Thus a regex pattern of `t*` will match zero or more occurrences of the letter `t`. Therefore, `payment*` literally matches `paymen` (not including the `t`), followed by zero or more occurrences of the letter `t`.

  If you want to match any character, we use another special regex pattern, a single period, `.`. If you want to match zero or more occurrences of any character, we follow the `.` with `*`. Thus, if you want to meant to match `payment` followed by zero ore more other characters, the regex pattern would be `payment.*`.
- Now, getting to the dollar sign: The `$` in a regex pattern also has a special meaning, namely “end of the line”. Thus `foo$` pattern will match “foo” that occurs at the end of the line. If you want to match a literal `$`, you have to escape it with a backslash, i.e., `\$`.
- Pulling this together, if the intent is to find matches of the string “payment” followed by any series of any characters, followed by a dollar sign, then the regex pattern would be `payment.*\$`. E.g.:

  ```swift
  let isFound = string.matches(#"payment.*\$"#)
  ```

In short, to find a literal dollar sign, one must escape it with a `\` in your regex pattern.

For more information about these various special characters in regular expression pattern strings, they are outlined in Apple’s [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsregularexpression#1661061) of `NSRegularExpression`.

---

As an aside, while one is free to use the old `.regularExpression` string searching option, in iOS 16 or macOS 13, or later, one might instead use the new [Regex](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/regex) syntax with `/…/` rather than extended string literals. E.g.

```swift
let isFound = string.contains(/payment.*\$/)
```

See WWDC 2022 video [Meet Swift Regex](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110357/).